# Flutter / Android not accessing file properly but web does

Tags: android, flutter, csv

I have a file called final.csv, located in the assets folder of my flutter project. I have added the file to the pubspec.yaml file.

```
assets:
  - assets/final.csv
```

When running the code with chrome browser, this works perfectly so I know the file is accessible and not empty as the data is parsed correctly. But when I run this with an Android Simulator from Android Studio, it returns my error of not being able to parse file. I've tried a million and one ideas but I can't get it too work.

If I upload file to server and change the code to pull file from url, it works perfectly but I don't want it too pull data every-time the page is loaded.

Anything obvious I'm missing.

```
    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchMarkers() async {
try {
    // Load the local file from the assets folder
    final csvFullString = await rootBundle.loadString('final.csv');

    // Parse the CSV content
    final csvFullList = const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvFullString);
    final dataRows = csvFullList.sublist(1); // Remove the header row
    final markers = dataRows
        .map((row) => {
              'name': row[0],
              'area': row[1],
              'road': row[2],
              'easting': row[3],
              'northing': row[4]
            })
        .toList();

    print('Parsing complete');
    return markers;
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Failed to load markers: $e');
  }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing the way you load the `final.csv` to:

```
final csvFullString = await rootBundle.load('assets/final.csv');
```

I did not try parsing the `csv` file (too lazy to deal with that) but it definitely is loading the content of the csv file into the object `csvFullString` in my case.
Your problem seems like was `loadString` since you're trying to load a binary file (`.csv`) and not a String.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: This didn’t work because load opens the file in memory as bytes so I then needed to add another line to decode the data to be parse as string. 

Even after doing that it did not work.